# bounds testing (Pesaran, Shin, and Smith)

Tags: time-series, cointegration

This deals with cointegration in the context  of Pesaran's ardl models. Specifically it deals with bound testing. It is not clear to me if you have to build an error correction model from your data (which normally involves differencing parts of it) to do bound testing of or if you can use the original ARDL model. My guess is that you can use the ARDL model, but although I have read a great deal of literature on this I have not found this point clearly addressed (or have not understood it).

Comment: Its interesting the R package ARDL generates exactly the same answer if you run the bound test on the original ARDL or you convert the ARDL to a Unrestricted ECM and then run the bound test on that. I am not sure if the software is converting the ARDL to a Unrestricted ECM before it runs the test or these two types of models will always generate the same bound test.

Comment: Hi: This doesn't answer your question but, if you go to cran and read the ARDL pdf, it gives all the gory details and the reference regarding the two bounds tests. The answer to your question is probably in there. Or, in the worst case scenario, the authors of the ARDL package will know and I bet that they will be glad to answer your question.

Comment: I have read it, in great detail. I ran it with an ECM and with the base ARDL in that package and the bound test generates exactly the same results. So if that package is correct it does not matter. Do you think the author would answer the question, I was hesitant to ask them.

Comment: I bet they would enjoy answering your question since packages such as the ARDL and bounds testing functions probably don't get heavy use. Therefore, I'm sure that the authors would be glad to know that someone is using ARDL.

Comment: I followed your advice and sent them several questions. Thanks.Still looking for a good introductory text on this method, although I have come to doubt there is such thing for time series.

Comment: I've never seen a book on bounds testing. In fact, I didn't know it existed before you mentioned it. :) I have a feeling that the author(s) will reply. Good luck. I think Pesaran wrote an econometrics textbook but I don't know of bounds testing is in it.

Comment: I am amazed I knew anything you did not - you obviously know stats better than I. But these days I have nothing to do but read stats all day long. And in honesty this has been true for years - strange job. I am really looking for an ARDL text, but I have not found one of these either.

Comment: Hi: thanks for complement but I might know VERY, VERY SPECIFIC things in time series reasonably well. But, it's a gigantic field so I don't know much.  As far as I do know, an ARDL text doesn't exist. The best you could probably so is take the Pesaran, Shin et al bounds test paper and then read all the references in that, if there are any. That's the only advice I can think of. Oh, you could also email Pesaran ( did he invent bounds testing ? ) and ask him what would be good to read. And, be thankful if they let you read about stats at work. That sounds like a great job if you ask me !!!!!

Comment: This looks like it was before bounds testing so might be good background ? All the best. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.153.3246&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Pesaran was one of three who apparently did create bound testing and the use of ARDL for cointegration(Shin and Smith were the other two). I have spent a lot of time recently looking for articles that use it, there are quite a few but since they are not methods articles they produce limited details. My job is actually to do stats and data analysis, in an organization that almost never does it (historically this is changing). To avoid terminal boredom I learned and run SQL, but most weeks I have little to do but learn new statistics and R :) Strange job.